# Django to modify value in body and return it

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

```
class LocationRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserAttributes
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):

        logger.info(self.context["request"].user.aerosimple_user)

        if UserAttributes.objects.filter(user_id=self.context["request"].data['user']).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("User Already exists.")
        user_attributes = UserAttributes.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return user_attributes
```

i want to change the value in the body and should return it with the changed value in the body

Comment: lohit what do you mean by body ???

Comment: under the if statement i need to write another if statement to add some input values and return them

Comment: what exactly you want to do with returned value?